# Lucene query search in Alfresco node browser

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I want to search for nodes who all are having locale other than "en_US". I tried the below query in node browser, but as result am getting all nodes irrespective of locale.

```
PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:sample/cm:documentLibrary//*"  AND -@sys\:locale:"en_US"
```

Am unable to figure out whats wrong in the query. Can someone please help...
Alfresco Version : Alfresco Enterprise v4.0.2(.9 38)..
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr:  Alfresco version : Alfresco Enterprise v4.0.2(.9 38)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Retrieve documents by sys:locale"](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/186319-retrieve-documents-by-syslocale)

> [...] the locale is stored differently in the SOLR (built on Apache Lucene) index. It is actually converted in small caps and a trailing underscore is added.

so, try this:

```
PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:sample/cm:documentLibrary//*"
AND -@sys\:locale:"en_us_"
```

Comment: Thanks....This really helped me.. I would like to add that i am using lucene indexing.and this query works for lucene indexing also. Can you please tell me is there any other such parameter which are stored differently?

Comment: "Solr is the popular, blazing-fast, open source enterprise search platform built on Apache Lucene"